# Using regex in Zabbix trapper item's key

Tags: zabbix

Does anyone know a way to use regex in Zabbix trapper item's key?

Example: the "regular" key would be 'trapper1.keyX' and I'd like for this trapper to grab anything with keys from 'trapper1.keyA' to 'trapper1.keyZ'.

Zabbix version in this scenario is 4.0:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

In this case, it might be useful to know what is your usecase to possibly suggest functional solutions.
For example, if you have a script parsing this data, adjusting the key in the script would make the most sense.

Update:
For ingesting data from another application with dynamic items, those items could be created via [LLD](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) - or, since 4.2, the [native Prometheus support](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/introduction/whatsnew420#prometheus_integration) can be handy.

Comment: I'm using this https://github.com/gmauleon/alertmanager-zabbix-webhook to send Prometheus alerts to Zabbix. Keys are constructed in the following manner: "staticPrefix.prometheusAlertName". So in order for it to work I'd need to construct as many Zabbix trappers as Prometheus metrics / alerts there are that I want to send. An awful lot of repetive work. I'm looking for a shortcut here.

Comment: "You can create your Zabbix Hosts/Items/Triggers yourself or you can use https://github.com/gmauleon/alertmanager-zabbix-provisioner"

Comment: @MarkWagner Yup, I was looking at that, but somehow did not feel that's the way to go for me. Ended up modifying the original webhook for my needs. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Richlv just noticed you edited your original answer. I know that Zabbix 4.2 supports Prometheus natively, however in this particular scenario update is not possible. As mentioned above, enden up modyfing the original webhook. Thanks!